# Prefilling a Cognito form

Tags: cognito-forms

I am really hoping someone would be able to help.

I have designed a long form containing around 50-60 fields of different types, some are conditional on others. I use this form to collect data from my customers. For a customer who has already submitted this form before, I want to have this form pre-filled with the information that was submitted last time. I have seen the ways in which a form can be pre-filled on Cognito website, but given that I have a long list of fields, manually inputting the field names and values is impractical. Is there any way to achieve this? A crude example coming to mind is to recordevery entry as a JSON and pulling up that JSON file by name if a customer opts to pre-fill the form.

I am open to embedding the form on a website or use the default Cognito link.

Comment: I closed this question as it looks like a support ticket, not as a practical, detailed question. See [tour], [ask], [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/88163)

Answer (score 0):

I’m a developer with Cognito Forms. Based on your description, I believe the [Entry Sharing](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/79/entries/sharing-entries) feature is more suited for your needs. With entry sharing, you can send links to your users that allow them to update their entries they’ve already submitted.

Comment: I don't want my customers to overwrite an entry they have already submitted, if that entry has been 'locked' - an entry would become locked or un-editable, say 4 months after it was first submitted. For a recent entry, ideally I should allow my users to edit the entry as long as it is not locked. Entry sharing could work if I can get my customers to 'copy' a previous entity to start a new form. Is that possible to do?

Comment: If you need to preserved your existing submission, then you could replicate your submissions to a new form and share those entries out. We recently helped a customer get their forms setup to accomplish this. Please submit a support request for more information, as this is not a documented capability of Cognito Forms.